# Grep password from .my.cnf

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I try to grep the (write access) password from .my.cnf, but I didnt get it yet.

The `.my.cnf` looks like this:

```
# longer
# comment text

[clientreadonly]
password=pass1 # comment
port=3306
user=test_ro
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
password=pass2 # comment
port=3306
user=test
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and I want to grep `pass2`. and the code shouldnt be too verbose of course. I ended up with

```
grep 'password=' ~/.my.cnf | sed -e 's/password=//
```

but thath actually leaves the `#comment` behind the `pass2` and I dont want to replace the whole comment (because its long in the original and stupid to just replace it). So I would need a regex to somehow get the `pass2` only.

The main target is, to grep the password so I can easily use it in a shell command line

Comment: now you need to explain on what basis `password=pass1 # comment` should be ignored

Comment: best would be on basis of the line previous to the pass (readonly), but it would be also ok just to take the second occurence

Comment: and there is always a space between text you need after `=` and before `# comment`?

Comment: yes, that can be assumed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[= ]' '/^password=/ && p !~ /clientreadonly/{print $2} {p=$0}' ~/.my.cnf
pass2
```

- `-F'[= ]'` use space or `=` as field separator
- `/^password=/ && p !~ /clientreadonly/` if line starts with `password=` and previous line doesn't contain `clientreadonly`

  - `print $2` print the second field
- `p=$0` save the previous line in `p` variable

Answer (score 1):

You can modify little bit like the following -

```
grep 'password=' ~/.my.cnf | sed -e 's/password=//' -e 's/ # comment//'
```

or other way -

```
grep 'password=' ~/.my.cnf | cut -d' ' -f1 | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Comment: the second one could work, but it returns both passwords like `pass1\npass2`

Comment: iam very sorry, there was a mistake in my question, I had pXassword for the first password, but that was just for debugging, originaly its also password

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
perl -00 -ane '/\[client\].password=(\S+)/s && print $1' < ~/.my.cnf
```

**Output:**

```
pass2
```

Comment: ah sorry, no does not work though, it returns both passwords, like `pass1pass2`

Comment: @Asara: then your sample file is not what you've given. In the question, it contains `pXassword=pass1 # comment`

Comment: maybe its possible, to use the second way with grep and take just the string after the space?

Comment: @Asara: Sorry I just can do it with Perl. See my edit

Comment: thank you very much, but I had to decide who has got the right answer, both of you have, the other one is just more explained

Comment: @Asara:No problem, glad it helps.